# IBM Watson Devices HTTP API gives 403 continuously

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-iot

I am trying to use HTTP APIs mentioned in below link to access my IoT devices and their data: https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Organization_Configuration/get

I am using my 6 digit organization code to access these apis and I have created API Key from IBM Watson to access these apis.

I am attaching snapshot of postman REST Api client, which I am using to send request from my local database to server.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your org ID does not need to be kept secret.  We would need it to confirm what it looks like, which is that your API key is not valid.

Comment: @PaulSlater Deleted api key and regenerated it again. Now Api is working.. will update answer soon.

Comment: @jimish We are also facing this problem using Postman. Actually Get request works for device using Basic Authentication, but create doesn't. Role is Standard Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your current api and create a new api from your IBM watson.

Copy that new api secret username and password at time of creation (as you can't see it once it's created) and put it to any rest client.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the version 1 APIs for the Watson IoT Platform?  Those were replaced by more powerful [version 2 APIs](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2016/05/05/ensure-you-are-taking-advantage-of-our-latest-apis/) last year and v1 has now been [deprecated](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/07/08/goodbye-watson-iot-platform-v1-api/).

Comment: Hey Valerie, yes we are using v2 APIs.